# How to train a neural network with an incomplete dataset?

Tags: neural-networks, accuracy, data-augmentation

I am currently training a neural network with a dataset containing approximately 10 features and 1000 entries.
The problem is that 70% of the entries contain at least one missing value for at least one of the features.

I am testing two different approaches:

1-Dropping all the incomplete entries, leaving me with 30% of the total data, to be split between training, validation and testing. I managed to get around 70% testing accuracy, which could definitely be improved.

2-Keeping all the entries, but replacing each of the missing values with the mean of all the values for that given feature. In this case, the accuracy is very low, around 50%.

How can I better use my data, in order to maximise the amount of data used for training? Maybe some kind of data augmentation technique (even though my data is not image, it only consists of numbers)?

Comment: One option you might consider is to impute the missing values with their nearest-correlated neighbor who isn't missing that value. You could measure the cosine correlation between each response. I imagine this will give you better accuracy, but you'll probably be over-fitting. How many missing values do you have? e.g. do you have 200 variables and each is missing 1 or 2, or 20 variables and each is missing 3 or 4?

Comment: Hi, there are 10 features for each row of the dataset, each feature has just one number. Each row might have from 1 to 5 features missing.

Comment: [tag:imputation]

Comment: Yeah, that's a pretty bad data set; I think you are always going to have some problems, but I would check out the imputation link @Reinstate Monica posted

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look.

Comment: I had a similar 70% missing entries problem performing non-negative canonical polyadic decomposition. Bayesian imputation with exponential priors on the unknowns worked nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Its not a complete solution for you but just a tip that you can increase a data set size exponentially via interpolation between the keys.   But doesnt always make sense,  but it does in alot of cases,  that between a big tree and a little tree there is a medium size tree.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/339490)